Prometheus PVC Structure
My question is about the structure of Prometheus and its storage configuration.
I installed Prometheus with kube-prometheus-stack helm chart and created a pv for it. After some time, I connected my node, and examine the Prometheus storage.
The container located in /var/lib/kubelet/pods/<prometheus-container-id> has 15 gb storage. On the other hand, the the pv path, /data/local-path-storage/pvc-<prometheus-pvc-id> has also 15 gb storage.
Does it mean that prometheus is using ephemeral storage for storing metrics or duplicate metrics it to PVC path and ephemeral storage path?
For example, minio ephemeral storage (/var/lib/kubelet/pods/<minio-container-id>) does not include pvc files in it.
